# How can I make the SD card work again after deleting necessary folders?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I was cleaning junk in SD card and I accidentally deleted some folders. And my tab is not showing system memory in settings or my ex SD card memory in settings. And I can not download anything on chrome or Google.if I want to download system apps apk in chrome it says you don't have SD card installed. If I transfer with Bluetooth same thing no memory card. I don't know what to do.but I can download some apps in play store. Please help me solve this problem. My tab is miki75 6628 ics2.   and it's rooted       Please tell me what to do?

Answer (score 1):

I think for starters you should back up any important files from the card, and then re-format it, wiping it completely. I'm not sure if it'll work, but it should trigger Android to recreate what it needs to. After that, you can copy any old data back to the card.

Comment: Did not work sir.still there nothing showing in settings storage. Just showing phone memory no internal memory or SD card memory.any other option sir.